# easyPHP Dev-server plug-in not installed

Tags: plugins, easyphp, devserver

I am currently working with a student on a project using easyPHP 16.1. The program/s install fine, and to begin with we can write & test PHP code with no problem. However, on 2 totally separate PCs we have had the same problem occur. Suddenly, for no apparent reason, pages which were working fail to function and we get the following error:-

Failed to connect to DB. Check that the username is valid.
Plugin '*C06327039E918D3247E4438D3785C723719DC8B5' is not loaded

We can't find any reference to this 'plugin' and wondered what is going on. On my own PC, I initially got round the problem by removing easyPHP then reinstalling it, but the student has several hand-ins depending on testing PHP code, and could do without the hassle of repeatedly having to 'fix' the installation. Is there a fix? Is it an easy fix? If there's no fix, should we just use an alternative like WAMP?

Answer (score 0):

This has been a serious issue for Easyphp since ver11.
so for me, after some time of use, I've just dropped using easyphp and switched over to WAMP.

From ver 16.1, Easyphp works in "portable mode" and becomes totally browser-based...

For a simple solution, I'd recommend to check out for alternate mySQL versions in your system, which can be interfering in the same port. Changing the Port No. can be useful in this case...